# Replacing "menu" with a logo using MMenu

Tags: jquery, css, mmenu

I'm using [MMenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) on a website and I'd like to replace the header that says "Menu" with a logo but can't figure out where to edit this.

Comment: pls post your code

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
      $("#mobile-menu").mmenu({
        "extensions": [
          "border-none",
          "pageshadow",
          "theme-dark"
        ],
        "navbar": {
          "title": "menu"
        },
        "navbars": [
          {
            "position": "top"
          }
        ]
      });
    });
  </script>`

Comment: @KarthikeyanSekar I posted it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for this example usage: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/demo/index.html?demo=menu-style-1&menu=default

If you look at the source script,

```
navbars     : [{
        height  : 3,
        content : [ 
            '<a href="#/" class="fa fa-phone"></a>',
            '<img src="inc/profile-2-w.png" />',
            '<a href="#/" class="fa fa-envelope"></a>'
        ]
    }, true]
```

adds images to the navbar.